# Зацикливание функции USB_disk_read в монтировании диска USB flash STM32

Tags: c, usb, stm32

После подсоединения флешки к МК STM32F105 и успешного получения переменной USB_MSC_HOST_STATUS значения **USB_MSC_DEV_CONNECTED**, столкнулся с проблемой монтирования. Выполнение входит в условие **if(UB_Fatfs_Mount(USB_0)==FATFS_OK)**

```
int main_usb(void)
{
  FIL myFile;   // обработчик файлов
  uint8_t write_ok=0;

  SystemInit(); // Инициализация настроек кварца

  // Инициализация светодиодов
 // UB_Led_Init();

  // Инициализация USB-OTG-порта как MSC-HOST
  // (для чтения / записи на USB флешку)
  UB_USB_MSC_HOST_Init();

  while(1)
  {
    // Данные о статусе USB
    if(UB_USB_MSC_HOST_Do()==USB_MSC_DEV_CONNECTED) {
      // если USB-флешка обнаружена
      //UB_Led_On(LED_GREEN);

      // Если файл еще не записан
      if(write_ok==0) {
        write_ok=1;
        //UB_Led_On(LED_RED);
        //Монтировать флешку
        if(UB_Fatfs_Mount(USB_0)==FATFS_OK) {
          // Редактировать файл, записанный в корень флешки
          if(UB_Fatfs_OpenFile(&myFile, "USB_File.txt", F_WR_CLEAR)==FATFS_OK) {
            // Написать несколько строк текста в файле
            UB_Fatfs_WriteString(&myFile,"Write string 1");
            UB_Fatfs_WriteString(&myFile,"Write string 2");
            UB_Fatfs_WriteString(&myFile,"Write string 3");
            // Закрыть файл
            UB_Fatfs_CloseFile(&myFile);
          }
          // Размонтировать флешку
          UB_Fatfs_UnMount(USB_0);
        }
        //UB_Led_Off(LED_RED);
      }
    }
    else {
      // Если нет доступных USB флешек
      //UB_Led_Off(LED_GREEN);
    }
  }
}
```

и далее заходит в функцию **USB_disk_read**:

```
int USB_disk_read(BYTE *buff, DWORD sector, BYTE count)
{
  int ret_wert=-1;
  BYTE status = USBH_MSC_OK;

  if(HCD_IsDeviceConnected(&USB_OTG_Core) && (USB_MSC_HOST_STATUS==USB_MSC_DEV_CONNECTED))
  {      
    do
    {
      status = USBH_MSC_Read10(&USB_OTG_Core, buff, sector, 512*count);
      USBH_MSC_HandleBOTXfer(&USB_OTG_Core ,&USB_Host);

      if(!HCD_IsDeviceConnected(&USB_OTG_Core))
      { 
        status=USBH_MSC_FAIL;
      }      
    }
    while(status == USBH_MSC_BUSY );
  } 
  else {
      status=USBH_MSC_FAIL;
  }


  if(status==USBH_MSC_OK) {
    ret_wert=0;
  }
  else {
    ret_wert=-1;
  }

  return(ret_wert);
}
```

После чего крутится в цикле do-while. Проходя через функции **USBH_MSC_Read10 и USBH_MSC_HandleBOTXfer** переменная **status** содержит значение **USBH_MSC_BUSY**. из-за чего выполнение кода не идет дальше. При этом при входе в функцию
**USBH_MSC_HandleBOTXfer** опрашивается значение параметра **USBH_MSC_BOTXferParam.BOTState**, который, как и все остальные параметры структуры равны 0:

```
typedef struct _BOTXfer
{
uint8_t MSCState;
uint8_t MSCStateBkp;
uint8_t MSCStateCurrent;
uint8_t CmdStateMachine;
uint8_t BOTState;
uint8_t BOTStateBkp;
uint8_t* pRxTxBuff;
uint16_t DataLength;
uint8_t BOTXferErrorCount;
uint8_t BOTXferStatus;
} USBH_BOTXfer_TypeDef;
```

В чем может быть причина данного зацикливания?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34820931/stm32-usb-otg-host-library-hangs-trying-to-create-file-with-fatfs

Comment: К сожалению, решение, которое предлагается в комментарии к предыдущей к ссылке безрезультатно. Изменения, которые предлагается внести в код, уже там имеются.